# To check whether a User Inputted string contains multiple separate segments, how would I be able to shorten the statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement, contains

I have written a program in which I take String input from the user and the user is expected to answer yes or no. I obviously am aware that users may not always answer in verbatim to the English Oxford dictionary, especially due to case sensitive nature of C# hence using the Contains method I test to ascertain whether any variations of Yes i.e., yes, Yes, YES, y, Ye, YEAH, Yeh, Yep, YEP etc and similarly for No.

Currently in my code I am employing the Contains function to check whether such a substring is present within the user inputted  string.

The line of code I am trying to shorten is below.

```
else if (UserInputCorrectnessTest.Contains("Yes") || UserInputCorrectnessTest.Contains("yes") || UserInputCorrectnessTest.Contains("y") || UserInputCorrectnessTest.Contains("it is"))
{
```

I have tried the above code, although I am expecting a shorter line of code that performs the same function.

Comment: Why don't you use keys?, for example ask the user to press `ENTER` or just use one word like `yes`

Comment: It is common to shorthand yes/no by y and  n single key input respective which makes the whole problem go away by using `ReadKey` instead.

Comment: ^^ most of the time, you'd even map the `Enter` key to a sensible default of the two.